# Heroes VI Altar of Wishes - Buying Creatures

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Do creatures you buy through the Altar of Wishes get assigned to your main Hero on each map?  I am wondering it they are really worth purchasing.  If they are faction specific this could lead to a large investment if one is planning on playing every faction.  If they require pre-built structures, then it would detract from the advantage of purchasing them through limited dynasty tokens.  In my opinion, the start game is the most crucial factor in a decisive victory.

Comment: Rolled back your edit so people can understand what the question was.  I'm sure other people have had the same question/confusion, and this way they can find it and the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot buy creatures in the Altar of Wishes. What you are purchasing is a creature's *icon* which you can use in place of a hero to display in your Dynasty.

Like titles, they're essentially worthless, and since you can't buy everything in the Altar of Wishes, focus on the Dynasty Weapons and Traits first.